# How to remove everything within a DIV except for one element?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://mintywhite.com/images/wg/0904/05rssfeedicons/rss-feed-icons11.jpg"/>
    TEXT NODE
    <span class="some_class">What the funk?</span>
    <form>What the monkey</form>
</div>
```

I want to remove everything within `div.item` except for the image. I tried using this bit of code, but the text node still remains within the `div`.

```
$('.item').contents().not('img').remove();
```

Any suggestions?

Here's my JSFiddle that you can fiddle with: http://jsfiddle.net/pSmDW/

Comment: The text still remains because it is not a DOM element. Try adding a `<span>` around it. Or I think you should make something like `$(".class").text() = "";` but not quite sure.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this: `$('.item').contents(':not(img)').remove();`

Answer (score 7):

```
var itm = $('.item');
var img = itm.children('img');
itm.empty().append(img);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pSmDW/2/

---

If there's any data or handlers on the image, we can use `.detach()`.

```
var itm = $('.item');
var img = itm.children('img').detach();
itm.empty().append(img);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pSmDW/3/

---

If there are several of these, you'll want to use `.each()`.

```
$('.item').each(function() {
    var img = $(this).children('img').detach();
    $(this).empty().append(img);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pSmDW/4/

Answer (score 2):

For jQuery v1.9.1 and below the following will work:

```
$('.item').contents(':not("img")').remove();
```

This will look for all elements (including text nodes) that aren't images and remove them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').contents(':not("img")').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>
    TEXT NODE
    <span class="some_class">What the funk?</span>
    <form>What the monkey</form>
</div>
```

For jQuery > 1.9.1 there is an issue when using `.contents()` with `:not()`. As a workaround you can grab the image, then replace the `.html()` of the element with the image.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imgNode = $('.item').find('img');
  $('.item').html(imgNode);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>
    TEXT NODE
    <span class="some_class">What the funk?</span>
    <form>What the monkey</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You could just use this instead for 2.1.1: $('.item').children(':not(img)').remove();

Comment: Although your answer does remove text elements, and my comment above doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The TEXT NODE needs to be wrapped in a html tag such as span.
I tried this with the JSFiddle you provided and worked no problems.
http://jsfiddle.net/pSmDW/1/

Good luck!
Tom

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://mintywhite.com/images/wg/0904/05rssfeedicons/rss-feed-icons11.jpg"/>
  **<span>TEXT NODE</span>**
    <span class="some_class">What the funk?</span>
    <form>What the monkey</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I disagree, My solution works. The contents method means that it doesn't need a span tag. I would agree however a span tag would be best practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Tom. Sorry, I wasn't clear in my question, but that's part of the problem - having text nodes that are not wrapped in an element.